# Pandas df.apply seems to be causing unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a piece of code like this:

```
import numpy as np
df111=[]
def getNoNaN(row_in,dflist):
    if np.sum(~pd.isna(row_in[3:])) > 1:
        dflist.append(row_in)
dftest.apply(axis=1,func=getNoNaN,dflist=df111)
df111[0]
```

And, got an unexpected result in the first row of df111.

```
df111[0]
Name     d4a0dad668a4249f8ddb8cfd336e3397
ID       f703f7b7e0173bc4269bfff2d8882439
Level                                   8
No.3                                  NaN
No.4                                  NaN
No.5                                  NaN
No.6                                  NaN
No.7                                  NaN
No.8                                  NaN
No.9                                  NaN
No.10                                 NaN
No.11                                 NaN
No.12                                 NaN
No.13                                 NaN
No.14                             0.55456
Name: 3615, dtype: object
```

This looks unusual since np.sum(~pd.isna(row_in[3:])) equals 1, I'm not quite sure why it's showing up in the df111 list.

It is worth noting that I now have a variety of solutions that can achieve similar functions normally (and very aware of the inappropriateness of the above code).

But this phenomenon still bothers me, maybe I missed some important hint in the Pandas documentation?
Hope to get your help.

Available test data can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuylSty8-8jmgZQE9_nY2cSYeEs1aw5v/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `apply`, you can use vectorized code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('apply_test_data.csv', index_col=0)
out = df[df.iloc[:, 3:].notna().sum(axis=1) > 1]
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                                  Name                                ID  Level  ...     No.12  No.13     No.14
0     ac64934249131b017d85de7b17556ebe  a015c9f38e2ebe6f900ed808119e4c2c      4  ...  0.232793    NaN       NaN
4     3b3d41ddd2c029057987db03c86cb351  43dd1452a809337189cfb0e32f3bc0da      4  ...  0.041589    NaN       NaN
7     5873a3f324dac3c389e0e1c570fe0b65  f34d7b40bf2848ab3f26390a14ece18e      5  ...  0.034054    NaN       NaN
10    a7b105839ac6343847216b21b391e1eb  7bfe373a31b9af37b6db07bbe17e113c      2  ...  0.285993    NaN       NaN
12    f0851646a101642c2cfa0d3a166104c8  e64f2e38c37509f4cb027fd77421a586      6  ...  0.101971    NaN       NaN
...                                ...                               ...    ...  ...       ...    ...       ...
3201  304507b189dd1c79ac9fdf88f7a12789  59fa7b6d602d9d4df4f4bba3750d9108     10  ...       NaN    NaN  0.519524
3218  fda0dabb9548ea30f824daab7d10b3d1  05d9b1e13f568b108306133d299598ad      7  ...       NaN    NaN  0.000820
3226  328d3ce95d79445f6885b2274549662d  b23f8565d14733bcda065add4987074c      3  ...       NaN    NaN  0.534249
3227  9c80e58c3308ddd40a9b1a8f59a09e3c  c86bf81b97bed0c099062910a0282b13      6  ...       NaN    NaN  0.000830
3243  ae9e52e41df532d1feea03f9ae0825fb  8b69d03591547968906c37a78dd81d51      2  ...  0.320757    NaN  0.022925

[1591 rows x 15 columns]
```

About your error: to solve your problem you have to make a copy each time you append a row (Series) in the list:

```
df111 = []
def getNoNaN(row_in,dflist):
    if np.sum(~pd.isna(row_in[3:])) > 1:
        # print(id(row_in))  # Uncomment to check the memory address of row_in
        dflist.append(row_in.copy())  # HERE
dftest.apply(axis=1, func=getNoNaN, dflist=df111)
```

Output:

```
>>> df111[0]
Name     ac64934249131b017d85de7b17556ebe
ID       a015c9f38e2ebe6f900ed808119e4c2c
Level                                   4
No.3                                  0.0
No.4                                  NaN
No.5                                  NaN
No.6                                  NaN
No.7                                  NaN
No.8                                  NaN
No.9                                  0.0
No.10                                 NaN
No.11                                 NaN
No.12                            0.232793
No.13                                 NaN
No.14                                 NaN
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your solution is more elegant than the one I used later.

Comment: Can I follow up with one question? Why copy() should be used, it seems that the original memory has not been modified. The cause of the error is what interests me more. Thanks again.

Comment: @JiangnanCrayonShin-chan. Check the memory address of each line. You will see it is always the same. So if you don't make a copy, `df111` is a list where all elements point to the last row of the dataframe.

Comment: It can help: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Igib.jpg

Comment: Oh, what a surprise! The picture is so loud and clear. Thank you very much, you are my good teacher!